Apply std::size on 0-sized array
The following code fails to compile:
// -std=c++17
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    int ar[0];
    static_assert(0 == std::size(ar));
    // error: no matching function for call to 'size(int [0])'
}

https://godbolt.org/z/cbYfhqhxa
I'm surprised that int [0] doesn't fit in:
template< class T, std::size_t N >
constexpr std::size_t size( const T (&array)[N] ) noexcept;

cppreference
Anyone could explain why? Thanks!
BTW, std::empty returns false for arrays which means it doesn't consider T [0] apparently.

int ar[0] is ill-formed as explained in the dupe.

See this answer that explains "If the expression is a constant expression, it shall have a value greater than zero."

Zero sized arrays are not standard C++, This is probably a compiler extension. See Array declaration "...an integral constant expression(until C++14)a converted constant expression of type std::size_t(since C++14), which evaluates to a value greater than zero..."

Arrays can't be declared to have zero size in standard C++. If your compiler permits it, then this is a compiler-specific language extension and it will be up to the compiler to decide how it integrates with the rest of the language constructs.
In template argument deduction if 0 is deduced for an array bound, then the deduction must fail in standard C++ (because array types with 0 do not exist). So it would make sense for the compiler to not permit it with the extension either, so that the extension won't interfere with the correctness of other standard constructs.

Though std::array can be declared with size 0.

Why do you use size when you know the size?

It's for demonstration purpose.
